Ratio of sample variance of higher-order moment compared to variance of a distribution
Let $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_l$ be iid samples from a distribution $D$ supported in $[0,1]$. We can define sample mean and variance as $\mu_X=\frac{1}{l} \sum_{i=1}^l X_i$ and $\sigma_X^2=\frac{1}{(l-1)} \sum_{i=1}^l (X_i-\mu_X)^2$. Let $\sigma^2$ denote the variance of $D$.
Let $Y_i=X_i^2$ for $i\in [l]$. We can define similarly $\mu_Y=\frac{1}{l}\sum_{i=1}^l Y_i$ and $\sigma_Y^2=\frac{1}{l-1}\sum_{i=1}^l (Y_i-\mu_Y)^2$.
In the above $\mu_X$ and $\sigma_X^2$ gives the sample mean and variance, and $\mu_Y$ and $\sigma_Y^2$ gives the sample second moment and its variance.
How large can $\sigma_Y^2$ be compared to $\sigma^2$? Also, is it known how large the ratio of $\sigma_Y^2$ and $\sigma_X^2$ can be?
In this question, we focused on the first and second moment. In general, one might ask this question for two arbitrary moments and also for more general distributions $D$ supported in some bounded interval $[a,b]$.
Thanks,
